# Is the deleted total space of a vector bundle over a paracompact space paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, paracompactness

In the introductory book by Milnor and Stasheff on characteristic classes, to define the Chern classes of some vector bundle $\varphi : E \to B$, we construct a vector bundle over the total deleted space $E_0$ of $\varphi$, where the total deleted space is the subspace of non-zero vectors in $E$. However, to have good properties, we frequently need to restrict to paracompact spaces. So it made me wonder: is the total deleted space paracompact? This is not discussed in the book.

The restriction of $\varphi$ to $E_0$ gives a $(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$-bundle over $B$, so we could generalize the question by asking if the total space of a $(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$-bundle over a paracompact Hausdorff space is paracompact. It seems likely to be true: by a result of Suzuki stated in [Product of paracompact spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158251/product-of-paracompact-spaces), for any paracompact Hausdorff space $X$, we have that $X \times (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$ is paracompact. However, an open subset of a paracompact space is not paracompact in general, so it is not easy to work locally. I should probably use the fact that a paracompact Hausdorff space is normal, but I'm not sure how.

I would be interested to have a direct proof or a reference. The question [Paracompactness of the projectified bundle over a paracompact space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094049/paracompactness-of-the-projectified-bundle-over-a-paracompact-space) seems really similar, but I'm not sure if it answers my question or not.

Comment: This probably isn't helpful, but I'd give it a strong "probably."

Comment: Pushouts along closed subspaces of paracompact spaces are paracompact. So you need to be able to find a trivialization of the vector bundle over a closed subspace. Presumably this is possible if the space is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi : E \to B$ be an $(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$-bundle, with $B$ Hausdorff paracompact, we will show that $E$ is paracompact. We can use the fact that the image of a paracompact space by a closed continuous map is paracompact ([proof here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-04/S0002-9939-1957-0087079-9/S0002-9939-1957-0087079-9.pdf) by E. Michael). Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of open subsets covering $B$ over which $\varphi$ is trivial, and which is locally finite. Then, we can find a collection $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ over the same index set $I$ with the same properties, and such that $\overline{V_i} \subseteq U_i$. Each $\overline{V_i}$ is paracompact, so $\overline{V_i} \times (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$ is paracompact, and therefore $\varphi^{-1}(\overline{V_i})$ is paracompact. The map
$$ \bigsqcup_{i \in I} \varphi^{-1}(\overline{V_i}) \to E $$
is surjective, and closed because the collection is locally finite. Thus, $E$ is paracompact.